# DMLOption-locale

Tags: apex

Does anyone know practical application or a sample code for
DMLOptions --localeoptions

Documentation says:

> localeOptions Property
>  The localeOptions property specifies the
>   language of any labels that are returned by Apex. The value must be a
>   valid user locale (language and country), such as de_DE or en_GB. The
>   value is a String, 2-5 characters long. The first two characters are
>   always an ISO language code, for example 'fr' or 'en.' If the value is
>   further qualified by a country, then the string also has an underscore
>   (_) and another ISO country code, for example 'US' or 'UK.' For
>   example, the string for the United States is 'en_US', and the string
>   for French Canadian is 'fr_CA.'

But i couldn't make it work with sample code below,I expected to see record in database in German below..May be i got the purpose of this all together wrong.please guide

```
Account a = new account(name=System.Label.label1);
database.dmloptions d = new database.dmloptions();
d.localeoptions ='de_DE';

database.insert(a,d);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your interpretation is not correct. It just change the labels you see on page. 
It will not do any translation of data.

More accurate example would be like this:

Notice that the labels are translated.

```
public void localeOptionsExample() {
try {
    connection.setLocaleOptions("en_US");
    connection.describeSObject("Account");

    connection.setLocaleOptions("en_DE");
    connection.describeSObject("Account");

  } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_localeheader.htm